# Nested ListBase/itemRenderer?

Tags: flex4, itemrenderer, flex-spark

I'm quite experienced in XAML/WPF but am new to Flex/Flex4. I'm trying to build a list of animatable objects with a sub-list of their animations using ListBase and inline ItemRenderers. Can someone shed any light on why the inner ListBase gives me the following error, while the outer list doesn't?

```
'spark.components.supportClasses.ItemRenderer' is not assignable to the default property, 'dataProvider', of type 'mx.collections.IList'.
```

The source code:

```
<s:ListBase dataProvider="{AnimationList}">
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer>
                <s:VGroup>
                    <s:Label id="labelDisplay"  text="{data.Name}"/>

                    <s:ListBase dataProvider="{data.Animations}">
                        <s:ItemRenderer>
                            <fx:Component>
                                <s:ItemRenderer>
                                    <s:HGroup>
                                        <mx:Button label="play" />
                                        <mx:Label text="{data.Name}"/>
                                    </s:HGroup>
                                </s:ItemRenderer>
                            </fx:Component>
                        </s:ItemRenderer>
                    </s:ListBase>

                </s:VGroup>
            </s:ItemRenderer>

        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:ListBase>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `<s:ItemRenderer>` (so it is an instance of `ItemRenderer` class assigned to `ListBase`'s default property which is `dataProvider`). I suppose it is typo and you're going to use property `<s:itemRenderer>` as in outer list. Take a look at first letter's case. In ActionScript all the classes starts with capitals.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that about an hour after posting but couldn't post an answer because of the 8 hour limit. Unfortunately the compiler couldn't give me a better error message, would've saved me a good few hours.

Comment: This error message will be more informative for you when you'll know Flex internals better :)